# Filter recordset from one table based on selected row from another table

Tags: mysql

I am working on a product configurator (php/mysqli) where a master table stores (page-by-page procedurally) IDs from associated option tables.

What I'm trying to do is filter option recordsets based on a previously selected/stored option compatibility.

The following example should illustrate:

**Master Table**

```
| ZOO_AREA_ID | ANIMAL_ID | ENCLOSURE_ID |
| 6           | 1         | 5            |
| 7           | 2         | 6            |
| 8           | 3         | ??????       |
```

**Animal Table**

```
| ANIMAL_ID | ANIMAL | ENCLOSURE_TYPE_IDS |
| 1         | Mouse  | 2,5,6              |
| 2         | Lizard | 6                  |
| 3         | Crab   | 3,4                |
```

**Enclosure Table (Options for menu list)**

```
| ENCLOSURE_ID | ENCLOSURE         |
| 1            | Large walled area |
| 2            | Wire Cage         |
| 3            | Oceanarium        |
| 4            | Water Tank        |
| 5            | Hutch             |
| 6            | Vivarium          |
```

So, if I'm configuring ZOO_AREA_ID row 8 in the master table and I have already selected and updated ANIMAL_ID 3 (Crab). I want to create a recordset for a drop-down that limits results in the Enclosure Table where the ENCLOSURE_ID is listed in the ENCLOSURE_TYPE_IDS of the Animal table.

In this case, the recordset result should be:

```
| ENCLOSURE_ID | ENCLOSURE  |
| 3            | Oceanarium |
| 4            | Water Tank |
```

What's the best way to achieve this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "The best way" is to write code that solves your problem. I don't think there is something ready

Comment: Your column name `ENCLOSURE_TYPE_IDS` suggests you're planning to store multiple IDs in there. That could cause problems later on. Best thing to do when you design a database is to [normalize](https://www.lifewire.com/database-normalization-basics-1019735) it.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware You're right in that I want to store multiple IDs in ENCLOSURE_TYPE_IDS.  That's because there are a number of enclosures that can house each type of animal.  Is there another way to approach this challenge?

Comment: @NicoHaase - simply saying I need to write code isn't helping me to write code LOL.  I didn't expect a copy/paste solution.

Comment: Well, then what did you expect? Do you have a problem structuring your application for this generic table structure such that it is shown user-friendly? Do you have problems in writing queries to perform the filtering?

Comment: @NicoHaase ???? I really don't understand what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware just for clarity, the ENCLOSURE_TYPE_IDS field is not a unique identifier and is not indexed.

Comment: I try to understand where you are stuck to make your question more understandable. Currently, I have no clue where to start helping you

Comment: @NicoHaase I'm trying to write select statement to filter results in the Enclosure Table, if ENCLOSURE_ID is stored in ENCLOSURE_TYPE_IDS from the Animal table.

Comment: So, the only problem is writing that query? What have you tried so far, where exactly are you stuck in doing this? Why does your database table contain question marks?

Comment: Another approach for the `ENCLOSURE_TYPE_IDS` is a "cross reference table", see: [The XREF table for MySQL](https://www.developerdrive.com/2011/12/the-xref-table-for-mysql)

Comment: Thanks @KIKOSoftware - I'm investigating this avenue now.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware The XREF Table solution works well.  Just took a while to sort out the SELECT statement but got there in the end - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of the ENCLOSURE_TYPE_IDS in the animals table and created a new XREF Table for instances where Animals (one column Integer IDs) were compatible with Enclosures (2nd column Integer IDs).

Then, for the required recordset....

SELECT e.* FROM enclosure_table e
LEFT JOIN animals_enclosures_xref xref ON xref.ENCLOSURE_ID = e.ENCLOSURE_ID
WHERE xref.ANIMAL_ID = :-whatever the link ID is-:

Think I've got that right but it is the end of the day.... :)